# Where is the function that rewards the miner address for mining the block?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, private-blockchain, consensus, geth-debugging

I have recently been digging into go-ethereum and have 'plugged' my own consensus mechanism which requires a node to solve a simple equation (2+2) etc to seal a block.
[image]

However, even after letting it run to 4392 blocks the miner address still has not received any eth?

[image]

Can someone point me in the right direction such as documentation of where the reward is given in the codebase? I cannot seem to find it. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone point me in the right direction such as documentation of where the reward is given in the codebase?

The static block reward is defined in [`consensus.go`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/41ac8dd803b646b5fa92354a983ee5df68253e2a/consensus/ethash/consensus.go#L42):

```
FrontierBlockReward       = big.NewInt(5e+18) // Block reward in wei for successfully mining a block
ByzantiumBlockReward      = big.NewInt(3e+18) // Block reward in wei for successfully mining a block upward from Byzantium
ConstantinopleBlockReward = big.NewInt(2e+18) // Block reward in wei for successfully mining a block upward from Constantinople
```

Later in the same file is [`accumulateRewards()`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/41ac8dd803b646b5fa92354a983ee5df68253e2a/consensus/ethash/consensus.go#L608):

```
// AccumulateRewards credits the coinbase of the given block with the mining
// reward. The total reward consists of the static block reward and rewards for
// included uncles. The coinbase of each uncle block is also rewarded.
```

Comment: Ah yes, I see now, I had to add ether during the finalize function using the coinbase address of that block. Cheers!